# Can I use BSD / MIT licensed code in a public-domain equivalent project?

Tags: mit, bsd, public-domain, permissive

As far as I know, the BSD 3-clause and MIT licenses are functionally equivalent.

Can I take BSD/MIT-licensed code and use it in a project which I then release under CC0, the Unlicense, or similar?

<sub>(I don't have any particular projects in mind at the moment, this is more of a "could I do this if I wanted to" question.)</sub>

**Update:** According to [this answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/5496/9449), you cannot, because of the notice requirement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot license the work as a whole under CC0. You do not have the ability to commit other authors' work to the public domain or remove an author's requirement that distribution of their work includes attribution.

You *can* release your *own* code under CC0, and include that code in a derivative work that also includes MIT/BSD-licensed code from other authors.